# clear any data:image from any value

Tags: php, image, base64

clear any data:image from any value

i have problem i have articles sties and while add some topics

found problem there an problem with words above 200,000 word

and when i see content see there an image  start with data:image and ending with 190,000 word

i try to found any php command to clear any data:image from any sting

i found that command

```
$sdkfjsdkjf='sdfsdfa  <img src="images/logo.png" width="181" height="92" alt=""> 
fasd fadsfadsf 
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABA......" />
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABA......" />
';
echo    $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) src="data:.*?"/i', '$1', $sdkfjsdkjf);
```

how to use it with content to replace all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should use `preg_match_all` to select all data you need to replace. Then use loop with `preg_replace` to replace it.

Look here: [preg_match_all](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: echo    $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) src="data.*?"/i', '$1', $sdkfjsdkjf);
  it's can work with it?

Comment: I dont really know what you mean by this post. Please, try to rewrite your message.

Comment: echo $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) src="data:.*?"/i', '$1', $sdkfjsdkjf);


i try by this command replace any img src have start with data: